# In what order does the Spring take the values in constructor-args

Tags: java, spring

I tried Constructor Injection of DI. This piece of code is working fine even if I don't specify the `type` in `<constructor-arg>`.

Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle {

    private String type;
    private int height;

    public Triangle(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Triangle(String type, int height) {
        this.type = type;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Triangle(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println(getType()+ " Triangle drawn with height = "+getHeight());
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Configuration file, spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id = "triangle" class = "model.Triangle">
        <constructor-arg value = "Isosceles"/> 
        <constructor-arg value = "20" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Driver class (`main` method) :

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();
    }
}
```

But, when I tried the lines of `<constructor-arg>` interchangeably in the `spring.xml`, an Exception was thrown as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

I'm not able to figure out in what order **Spring** takes the values from the `<constructor-arg>`.

Comment: Avoid XML based configuration if you can.

Comment: @BoristheSpider BTW why? Just wondering

Comment: @Andremoniy the Spring community is moving away from XML based configuration. The main reason, as far as I can see, is that Java based configuration adds much more compile time type safety so it's more robust. This mirrors the movement of JavaEE away from `web.xml` etc to a combinations of convention-over-configuration and metadata based configuration.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That's interesting. I thought it moves towards balanced configuration spread between XML and Java annotations. Are any authoritative papers about this?

Comment: @Andremoniy if you look at something like Spring Boot, that's almost entirely convention (autoconfigure) based with the ability to override behaviour using JavaConfig. Not sure I've seen anything I would call authoritative - will have a think.

Comment: I find XML based configuration easier to read. All the beans are in 1 place (or maybe spread in a few XMLs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short answer: It takes arguments in the same order as they were described in the class constructor.

A proof from [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection) (p.7.4.1):

> Constructor argument resolution matching occurs using the argument’s
>   type. If no potential ambiguity exists in the constructor arguments of
>   a bean definition, then the order in which the constructor arguments
>   are defined in a bean definition is the order in which those arguments
>   are supplied to the appropriate constructor when the bean is being
>   instantiated.

Comment: Now, I figured out that a type mismatch has occurred when i used the `<constructor-arg>` values interchangeably.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with you, you can write the `<constructor-args>`  in the same order as of class constructors. You can also specify index in the `<constructor-args>` as below:

```
<constructor-arg index = "0" value = "Equilateral"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index = "1" value= "20"></constructor-arg>
```

so here `index` can be used if you want to resolve between multiple constructors depending on the order of their parameters.
 So it will look up for a constructor with two arguments

- first argument will be set to "**Equilateral**" with `index = "0"`
  i.e. `type = Equilateral`.
- Second argument will be set to "**20**" with `index="1"`i.e. `height= 20`.

You can also interchange your `<constructor-args>` as follows:

```
<constructor-arg index = "1" value= "20"></constructor-arg>     
<constructor-arg index = "0" value = "Equilateral"></constructor-arg>
```

Your program will execute without any Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093189/7004388) helped me to write an answer for my question. 
This is my Constructor:

```
public Triangle(String type, int height) {
        this.type = type;
        this.height = height;
    }
```

It takes,

- `type` (instance variable) of type `String` as the first argument and,
- `height` of `int` type as a second argument.

So, in the spring.xml file, the values that we provide in `<constructor-arg>` should be in the same order as the class's constructor. So when I tried to use these lines, an exception was thrown.

```
<constructor-arg value = "20" />
<constructor-arg value = "Isosceles"/>
```

The reason is,

> - First argument '`20`' will be takes as a String and sets the `type` instance variable.
> - For the second argument '`Isosceles`', the type mismatch ( `String` to an `int` conversion ) takes place for the `height` instance
>     variable.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Spring%20can%20convert%20a%20value%20supplied%20in%20string%20format%20to%20all%20built-in%20types%2C%20such%20as%20int%2C%20long%2C%20String%2C%20boolean%2C%20and%20so%20forth